# Non-discriptive error when combining minted and libertine

Tags: minted, libertine

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
This does not seem to work.
\end{document}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
$ pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -enable-write18  -recorder --jobname="the-notes"  "main.tex"

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mweights/mweights.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontaxes/fontaxes.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/LinLibertine_I.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/minted/minted.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/fvextra/fvextra.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.sty
Style option: `fancyvrb' v2.7a, with DG/SPQR fixes, and firstline=lastline fix 
<2008/02/07> (tvz)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/upquote/upquote.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mdseries@tt 

l.562 ...FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft}{\ttfamily xxxx}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on the-notes.log.
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's seems to be some interference between mweights.sty (used by libertine.sty) and minted.sty. You can either interchange the \usepackage calls or add

```
\makeatletter
\def\mdseries@tt{m}
\makeatother
```

between them.

Comment: The same issue appears when using the ACM transaction style (acmart documentclass) in combination with `\usepackage{minted}`. The document class acmart loads mweights.sty. To resolve this issue, put the commands `\makeatletter \def\mdseries@tt{m} \makeatother` as suggested in this answer in front of the `\usepackage{minted}` command.

Answer (score 3):

It is the fault of the `mweights` package: It redefines font commands like `\ttfamily` so that they now use internal commands like `\mdseries@tt`, but defines these internal commands only at the begin of the document. So you no longer can use these commands in the preamble:

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{mweights}
\ttfamily
\begin{document}
blub
\end{document}
```

You get the error as `fvextra` package used by minted contains

```
\settowidth{\FV@BreakSymbolIndentLeft}{\ttfamily xxxx}
```

which means that it does typesetting in the preamble -- something that one should better avoid and doesn't make much sense anyway as the fonts can still change -- but shouldn't give an error.

Answer (score 1):

I too encountered this issue when using `minted` package with 2016 Tex distribution.  However, I do not see the issue with 2017 Tex distribution.  So, upgrading to 2017 Tex may be one way to fix the issue.

Comment: That's not quite an answer to the question. But it might be a relevant information as a comment. I'm aware you haven't got enough information to comment. Would you like me to leave this as a comment to the question for you?

Comment: @gusbrs I have updated my answer to suggest "upgrading is a solution".  Yes, it would be good if you can "change" my answer into a comment to the question.

Comment: As you edited it to convert it into an answer, I believe it's ok to leave it here then. BTW, welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: ah!, in the first comment, I meant reputation of course, not information. ;)